# Oracle Jdbc CallableStatement fails with plsql contains CR ("\r")

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, carriage-return

I make a simple java program to read plsql block from a text file then execute it via `CallableStatement`.

If the text file uses both CRLF ("\r\n"), the execution fails with `ORA-06550` and `PLS-00103` (Encountered the symbol "").

Meanwhile, it works fine if the text file use only LF.

NG:

```
BEGIN\r\nNULL;\r\nEND;
```

OK:

```
BEGIN\nNULL;\nEND;
```

Answer (score 0):

*nux vs. Windows linefeeds, bet your server is *nix and it sees \r as part of the statement.

Comment: I'm not in charge of database management so I use `SELECT PRODUCT, VERSION FROM SYS.PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION;` to check the database info and it shows `TNS for 64-bit Windows:  10.2.0.5.0`. I guess it's a windows server.

Answer (score 0):

Either the files do not match the examples or the text must be translated by some other process before it's sent to Oracle.  Both of the examples work fine on Oracle, regardless of the version and operating system.  It might help to build the command as a string and use `DUMP` in a `SELECT` statement to see exactly what characters are sent to Oracle.

The code below runs without error, demonstrating that any combination of line feed and carriage return is sufficient to separate the keywords.

```
declare
    lf varchar2(1) := chr(10);
    cr varchar2(1) := chr(13);
begin
    execute immediate 'begin'||lf||'null;'||lf||'end;';
    execute immediate 'begin'||cr||lf||'null;'||cr||lf||'end;';
    execute immediate 'begin'||cr||'null;'||cr||'end;';
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're correct that both CRLF and LF work fine while being executed directly on Oracle, but my issue relates to the JDBC's `CallableStatement`

Comment: But those error messages are coming from Oracle, not Java.  I think the program is not sending the string you think it's sending.

Comment: You think correct again and that's what I'm asking in my post (oracle jdbc `CallableStatement` 's issue).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by replacing all line breaks before using the file content:

```
plsqlText = plsqlText.replace("\r\n", " ");
```